# How to break out of a function

Tags: c++, function, return, break

If I have a function as follows:

```
void func () {
    //...

    if (condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

When I use break it gives me an error. Is there another way to exit a function using an if condition and to complete compiling the code normally?

Comment: This is probably due to the misconception that if is denoted as "if loop" by many people. Actually it is "if condition".

Comment: Try ```return;```

Answer (score 38):

break is used in loops and switch statement. use `return` instead.

Comment: Note that `return` works even if the function has a `void` return type. You just write `return;` in that case.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use **'return'** in place of break when you want to run rest of code normally.

Use **'break'** in case of switch or for loop for normal execution

Use **'exit'** for force stop in execution

Answer (score 6):

use `return;`:

`if(/*condition*/) { return; }`

Answer (score 4):

Just use `return`.

More info can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement).

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you can `return` from a function any time you want.

Answer (score 1):

`break` is to exit a loop or a `switch` construct.

Instead, use `return` with an optional value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `return` statement that return nothing.
Like:

```
if(predicate)
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the increment variable to a number that causes the loop to break. For example-

```
void calculate() { 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) { 
       i=11; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: that is not quite the answer, Shadi asked how to exit the function, a void return would do the trick.