# How to stop execution of if-statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Hi I want to stop the execution of if-loop ,I have tried with 'return' statement but its exits from the function ,So how can I exit from the single if Statement.I have tried with following code...

Here I want to stop execution of if(CheckHorizontalSide(SourceMember)) and by stopping this I want to move towards the if(CheckTop(SourceMember))

```
void A()
{


      if (CheckHorizontalSide(SourceMember))
        {

            if (lblHorizontalMember.Text == DestinationMember)
            {

                lsRelationPath.Add(lblHorizontalMember.Text);
                lblRelationPath.Text = String.Join("-", lsRelationPath);
                lblRelationPath.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

            bool WhetherContains = lsRelationPath.Contains(SourceMember);
            if (WhetherContains)
            {
                return;
            }

            //This below code is not related to the above 'WhetherContains '
            lsMemberID1.Clear();
            lsRelationPath.Add(lblHorizontalMember.Text);


            Find_Route(lblHorizontalMember.Text, DestinationMember);
        }


    if(CheckTop(SourceMember))
    {
    //code here....
    }
}
```

Comment: which if are you talking about? First or second?

Comment: Which If you want to stop executing, and if you want that why you write in first place.

Comment: Please see my edited explanation

Comment: you can not achieve this behavior in the same method. Just break the if statements into separate methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523538/how-do-i-break-out-of-an-if-statement

Answer (score 1):

You put the rest of the block in a sub-block with `{ }` and put `else` in front of that.

You can nest as deeply as you want but you might try factoring out blocks to helper functions to reduce the complexity and give statements a name.

```
 if (WhetherContains)
 {
     // this is actually empty
 }
 else
 {
     lsMemberID1.Clear();
     lsRelationPath.Add(lblHorizontalMember.Text);    
 }
```

Or,

```
 if (!WhetherContains)
 {
     lsMemberID1.Clear();
     lsRelationPath.Add(lblHorizontalMember.Text);    
 }
```