# Converting to lowercase at end of statement?

Tags: c++, character, uppercase, lowercase

Slight issue. (Not using toupper() and tolower() functions) I understand what converting to uppercase and lowercase using numerical values is but following my C++ book, why is the conversion at the end of this statement and not before?:

```
if (letter >= 'A')  //test for 'A' or larger
    if (letter <= 'Z')  //test for 'Z' or smaller
    {
        cout << endl
             << "You entered a capital letter."
             << endl;
        letter += 'a' - 'A'; //Convert to lowercase
        return 0;
    }

if (letter >= 'a') //test for 'a' or larger
{
    if (letter <= 'z') //test for 'z' or smaller
    {
    cout << endl
         << "You entered a small letter."
         << endl;

    return 0;
    }
}
```

Why would it convert the uppercase to lowercase at this point of code execution since the second if statement deals with lowercase input?

Comment: In this day and age, this kind of conversion should be banned.

Comment: @AndyProwl Why? `'a' - 'A'` is a constant. There'd be no point in assigning a constant to the letter. `+=` converts to lowercase with this technique.

Comment: Careful: `char` may be either signed or unsigned. `'a'-'A'` may underflow if unsigned type.

Comment: @H2CO3 - += converts to lowercase **if** the system uses ASCII to encode characters **and** the code only has to deal with characters in the English alphabet. As soon as you add accented characters into the mix, or, heaven forbid, Cyrillic or Greek, this code will fail.

Comment: @PeteBecker you think I don't know that? My goal was to point out that (assuming ASCII) it should be `+=` and not `=`...

Comment: @H2CO3 - sorry, I mis-aimed a general rant about the original code. If this code was taken from a book, the book should be taken out and shot.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh, I see. No problem then. (Yes, it should, though yI don't know much systems where this would break anything.)

Comment: @H2CO3 - with EBCDIC, there are a bunch of non-alphabetic characters that are numerically in the middle of the alphabetic ones. So, for example, the code would report that `'~'` is lowercase, and that `'}'` is uppercase (but not '`{`').

Comment: @PeteBecker Good find, but Wikipedia says we're 50 years too late to care: "EBCDIC descended from the code used with punched cards and the corresponding six bit binary-coded decimal code used with most of IBM's computer peripherals of the late 1950s and early 1960s."

Comment: @H2CO3 - that's when it was introduced. But read on: "All IBM mainframe and midrange peripherals and operating systems use EBCDIC as their inherent encoding...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would it convert the uppercase to lowercase at this point of code
>   execution since the second if statement deals with lowercase input?

That is because

```
return 0
```

means that the function is finished. The lines

```
if (letter >= 'a') //test for 'a' or larger
{
    if (letter <= 'z') //test for 'z' or smaller
    {
    cout << endl
         << "You entered a small letter."
         << endl;

    return 0;
    }
}
```

will not be executed if letter was originally an upper case letter. It would print out "You entered a capital letter.", then convert it to lower case, then exit.

> why is the conversion at the end of this statement and not before?

It would make no difference if the conversion were before the cout statement.

Answer (score 3):

The given snippet could be the body of the function:

```
int convert(char& letter)
{
    if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')
    {
        letter += 'a' - 'A';
        return 0; // go out of this function...
    }
    else if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
    {
        letter += 'A' - 'a';
        return 0; // go out of this function...
    }
    return -1; // it wasn't a letter as we expected
}
```

Note, that there's a possible path that doesn't match none of these 2 situation. Let's say that `letter` is `'?'`, since you're returning `int` value, there should be an indication that something is wrong (it's up to you how you deal with error handling).

Possible usage of your this function could look like this:

```
char letter = '!';
if (convert(letter) == 0)
    // success ...
else
    // error ...
```

If the question is really about leaving the scope of function, then this question could be helpful too:
[How to break out of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302227/how-to-break-out-of-a-function)

---

Concrete example:

```
void convertLetterAndPrintResult(char& letter)
{
    if (convert(letter) == 0)
        std::cout << letter << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "ERROR: '" << letter << "' is not valid character!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char letter = '!';
    convertLetterAndPrintResult(letter);
    letter = 'g';
    convertLetterAndPrintResult(letter);
    letter = 'L';
    convertLetterAndPrintResult(letter);
}
```

Output:

```
ERROR: '!' is not valid character!
G
l
```

Comment: Thank you. That question is also helpful and will be looking back at it when I get to the stage of breaking out of functions. However, my question was, in a nutshell, why convert uppercase to lowercase before the return statement. But I am sort of starting to get a grip on it.

Answer (score 2):

Because there's a `return 0;` statement in the first part. If the original character was uppercase, the control flow doesn't even reach the second nested `if () { if () { } }` part.

Comment: I understand that but in that scenario would it not be better to check and convert the letter characters before hand? It just doesn't make sense to me why one would convert to lowercase right before return ends the operation.

Comment: @wilbomc: `return` doesn't terminate program's execution, it just makes the execution to leave the function that has been called and to pass the returned value to the caller. Check my answer now :)

Comment: I thought _return_ basically returned control of a program to the operating system thus ending it. But I am still in early days learning C++. So _return_ is basically returning the lowercase value?

Comment: @wilbomc Read that C++ turorial again :) `return 0;` simply returns 0. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I re-read the tutorial. I am now under the impression the author was simply showing a way to convert to lowercase and uppercase but wrote it in a confusing manner as, I guess (might be wrong), there is no need for the lowercase conversion in the first place, at least in the example I wrote. The conversion would be better of validating user input in my opinion. But I'm just a beginner.